# Not able to get getOutputStream() working in servlet

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, servlets

I am sending a json object to servlet and calling servlet through a function. Here is my jsp page and function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function retrieveTicketsExcel(){
    var jsonData = {};
    jsonData["tower"]=$('#appTower').val();
    jsonData["sDate"]=$('#startDate').val();
    jsonData["eDate"]=$('#endDate').val();
    jsonData["apps"]=$('#appfilter').html();
    jsonData["duration"]=$('#duration').val();
    jsonData["severity"]=$('#severity').val();
    jsonData["releasetype"]=$('#releasetype').val();
    jsonData["query"]=$('#query').val();

         $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                url:"retrieveTicketsToExcel.htm",
                data:'requestData='+JSON.stringify(jsonData),
                dataType: "json",

            });
         }
</script>
    <div class="modal-footer">
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Export" onclick="javascript:retrieveTicketsExcel();">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
```

Now i am calling Servlet method which is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieveTicketsToExcel.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void retrieveTickets(@RequestParam("requestData") String requestData, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    // userDAO.setDataSource(dataSource);
    System.out.println("*****************/GRTBDashboard/retrieveTicketsToExcel****************");
    Map<String, String> requestMap = new Gson().fromJson(requestData, Map.class);

    response.reset();
    response.resetBuffer();

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.addHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "Attachment;filename=\"Ticket_Details.xls\"");
    ServletOutputStream fileOut = response.getOutputStream();

    System.out.println("retrieveTickets - > " + requestData);
    List<DashboardData> dashboardDataList = null;
    String tower = requestMap.get("tower");
    System.out.println(tower);
    try {
        dashboardDataList = userDAO.retrieveTickets(requestMap);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final double noOfRecords = dashboardDataList.size();
    double count = Math.ceil(noOfRecords / 30000);
    try {

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        short dateFormat = workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

        Iterator<DashboardData> iterator = dashboardDataList.iterator();

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            int c1 = 1;
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(tower);

            HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
            font.setFontName("Verdana");
            style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
            style.setFillPattern(style.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
            font.setColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);
            style.setFont(font);
            HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
            ;

            header.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Type"));
            header.getCell((short) 0).setCellStyle(style);

            header.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Ticket Number"));
            header.getCell((short) 1).setCellStyle(style);

            header.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Open Date"));
            header.getCell((short) 2).setCellStyle(style);

            header.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Closed Date"));
            header.getCell((short) 3).setCellStyle(style);

            header.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Reported By"));
            header.getCell((short) 4).setCellStyle(style);

            header.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Severity"));
            header.getCell((short) 5).setCellStyle(style);

            header.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Assigned App"));
            header.getCell((short) 6).setCellStyle(style);

            header.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Status"));
            header.getCell((short) 7).setCellStyle(style);

            int rowIndex = 1;

            while (iterator.hasNext() && c1 <= 30000) {
                DashboardData dashboardData = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Data : "+dashboardData.getTicketNumber());
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);

                HSSFCell cell0 = row.createCell((short) 0);
                cell0.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getType()));

                HSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell((short) 1);
                cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getTicketNumber()));

                HSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell((short) 2);
                cell2.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getOpenDate().toString()));

                HSSFCell cell3 = row.createCell((short) 3);
                cell3.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getClosedate().toString()));

                HSSFCell cell4 = row.createCell((short) 4);
                cell4.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getReportedBy()));

                HSSFCell cell5 = row.createCell((short) 5);
                cell5.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getPriority()));

                HSSFCell cell6 = row.createCell((short) 6);
                cell6.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getAssignedGroup()));

                HSSFCell cell7 = row.createCell((short) 7);
                cell7.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dashboardData.getStatus()));
                c1++;

            }
            for (int autosize = 0; autosize <= 10; autosize++) {

                sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) autosize);
            }

        }

        workbook.write(fileOut);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != fileOut)
            fileOut.close();
    }
    fileOut.close();
    fileOut.flush();
}
```

I am trying to flush out data as excel which i am writing but on clicking export button does all but giving download on jsp page.
If i am trying to write using `FileOutputStream()` it is writing perfectly on my disc. But i want to use `response.getOutputStream()` to download in jsp page.

Comment: Do you have an error being shown ?
It could be an exception due to closing and flushing after the close in the finally

Comment: I am getting no error. i even tried removing finally block, but no use

Comment: What is happening when you click on your button ? Do you even know if your controller's method is actually called ?

Comment: Some ideas: 

Try rethrowing the exceptions instead of call printStackTrace (`throw new RuntimeException("some error", e);`) . If the stderr is badly redirected in the webserver you'll miss the error

Try debugging the server

Trace the network call using the Developper console in Chrome

Comment: controller method is definitely called because i am able to write if i use `FileOutputStream` but nothing happens if i use `response.getOutput()`

Comment: @Benoît : tried, i am not getting any runtime error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is in the JQuery side?

Can you get the download working by opening `retrieveTicketsToExcel.htm` manually in the browser? If so, then try using `window.location.href="retrieveTicketsToExcel.htm"` instead of JQuery's ajax();

Edit:
I am now quite sure the problem is in the Query side. First of all, ajax requests can not initiate file download dialogs. `window.location.href` or submitting a form are your options here.

Also, you are providing `json` as a dataType in your ajax call. This is wrong because dataType specifies the type of data that you're expecting back from the server, not the format of the request you're sending (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Edit2:

Your use of `data:'requestData='+JSON.stringify(jsonData)` is also problematic. You can not simply appent JSON string to an url. You need to encode it first. Try using
`data:'requestData='+ encodeURI(JSON.stringify(jsonData))`

Or better yet, use a POST request since this seems semantically more correct. That way you would not  need the `requestData=` part, but would also have to change the servlet code a bit. You'd need to read the json from Servlet inputStream or reader directly.

Something like this:
`new Gson().fromJson(request.getReader(), Map.class);`;

Comment: `window.location.href="retrieveTicketsToExcel.htm"` gives me page not found.

Comment: oops, you ought to use `window.location.href="/retrieveTicketsToExcel.htm";`

Comment: i tried both but getting `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().`,

Comment: You need to encode the JSON first if you wanna append it to an url. I amended my answer, more details there.